# Create groups of targets

Tags: drake-r-package

Let's say that I have the following plan:

```r
test_plan = drake_plan(
    foo = target(x + 1, transform = map(x = c(5, 10))),
    bar = 42
)
```

Now I want to create a new target that contains the two subtargets foo_5, foo_10 and the target bar. How can I do this? I feel it must be super simple but I don't manage to get a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is both possible and simple. The built-in solution is to use tags: https://books.ropensci.org/drake/static.html#tags. Example:

```r
library(drake)
drake_plan(
  foo = target(
    x + 1,
    transform = map(x = c(5, 10), .tag_out = group)
  ),
  bar = target(
    42,
    # You need a transform to use a tag, even for 1 target.
    transform = map(tmp = 1, .tag_out = group)
  ),
  baz_map = target(group, transform = map(group)),
  baz_combine = target(c(group), transform = combine(group))
)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   target         command                
#>   <chr>          <expr>                 
#> 1 foo_5          5 + 1                  
#> 2 foo_10         10 + 1                 
#> 3 bar_1          42                     
#> 4 baz_map_foo_5  foo_5                  
#> 5 baz_map_foo_10 foo_10                 
#> 6 baz_map_bar_1  bar_1                  
#> 7 baz_combine    c(foo_5, foo_10, bar_1)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is great, I was not able to understand the tags by reading the docs, but now I see their power. Thanks!